# Rails form helper select method arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am wondering why there is an extra argument `{}` in the following form helper for `select` in Rails.

```
<%= f.select :genre_ids,
          @genres.map { |g| [g.name, g.id] }, {}, { multiple: true } %>
```

I read some documentations on select helper, and understand that the second argument `@genres.map { |g| [g.name, g.id] }` returns the format that `select` method expects the choice to be on. But I can't find any example where there is a blank hash as a third argument as shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the empty hash as the third argument is because you have a value in the hash for the fourth argument.

Both the third and fourth arguments for `select` default to empty hashes ([per the documentation for select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)) but when you set the fourth (or Nth) argument where the N-1 argument is implicitly set in the called method, you must explicitly set the third (or N-1) argument.

tl;dr - If you don't explicity declare the empty hash as the third argument, `{ multiple: true }` will be passed as the third argument and the fourth argument will be the implied empty hash, per the docs.

Comment: As per the document, `select` takes `object`, `method`, `choices`, `options = {}`, `html_options = {}` arguments. I am trying to wrap my head around it: in my example, can you tell me which argument corresponds to which?

Comment: Right, so, using `form_for`, `object` is implited by `form_for`, specifically the `f.select`.  So remaining are `method` (which you have as `genre_ids`), choices (the `@genres.map ...`), `options` which is the explicit empty hash, and `html_options` (which you have as `{ multiple: true }`).